# Java Controller and Service validations

Tags: java, spring

We got this design:
Rest Controller -> Calling Service -> Calling JPA DAOs

Let say we save employee. And we have a requirements to validate employee name.

**IEmployeeService.saveEmployee(Employee emp)
EmployeeController.saveEmployee(Employee emp)**

**Option 1:** I can inject JSR303 annotations on Employee and Let Rest Controller validate it as part of automatic validation.

**Option 2:** I validate in service method and raise exception and let controller to return proper JSON of that exception.

Seems like service should have validation anyways... but in presence of JSR303 annotations controller is doing everything, hence there seem to be duplication of logic if service does those checks as well.

How do you approach? Everybody's comments welcome and will be appreciated.

Thanks
Babar

Comment: I don't see the link between *Test Driven Development* and the question where validation should occur. Besides that, your question depends on your context, your code. I think https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ is a better place for this kind of question.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, the standard way is to use both Opt 1 and Opt 2.

But, you have to define what's going to be validated in each layer.

This is my favorite approach:

1. Validate field constraints in Controller. This include: Date format, string length, min, max, null... validation
2. Validate business logic constraint in Service. Include: Unique, exist check, from date < to date, max items per group of entities...

One side note: Entity should never been exposed to outside world. We should have some kind of converter logic to convert entity to output JSON/model

Comment: I agree we should expose DTOs... question remains same... if first name and last name in DTO is not null, we should put checks at controller level possibly using JSR annotations and same checks on service input as well.... is that you referring as well? We can't really do selective checks in multiple layers as both layers are public... because service might be called from different other controllers...

Comment: No, null check should be done from controller. Service should validate business logic only

Answer (score 0):

Ideally your web facing part should have your validation logic implemented. The service layer should be purely for the business part of project. It is also security best practice before it reach to your service layer code. Nowadays  people do mix-up layer and want to do everything in same layer. The `jsr-303` annotation are bean level validation. So normally it is applied at a place where model comes into picture.

So you can do that at

1. controller layer: to validate your input and other min/max range and basic validation.
2. service layer: To have any specific validation at service layer by Autowiring `javax.validation.Validator`.

Comment: I agree we should expose DTOs... question remains same... if first name and last name in DTO is not null, we should put checks at controller level possibly using JSR annotations and same checks on service input as well.... is that you referring as well? We can't really do selective checks in multiple layers as both layers are public... because service might be called from different other controllers

Comment: it really depends on your use case. If your have different microservices implementing service layer then your have a point. If you have service and controller layer part of same application then you can have the approach which i suggested. In case question of calling from other controller, The respective controller should have basic jsr Validations(similar to first controller) in place to pass proper data. As already said, All your web facing components should have proper validation in place. else your app might be compromised.

Comment: Thanks... so you saying on general grounds it is OK for a service to ignore NULL checks because in our application they are behind controllers and they do that. I am coming from the concept of unit, while writing JUnit for Service you focus on that unit and make sure you have valid checks... because nevertheless they are public methods. I agree your point of web facing end points... that is why I am here to clarify as I have all checks on controller layer but service is left for only DB level checks that makes sense a little.

Comment: Yes for unit testing we actually consider single operation as unit. So if we keep the redundant null checks at every layer, it gone affect the performanance as well. Once your exception hierarchy is well defined, in case of any unexpected input to service the exception can be propogated back to caller (i.e. in this case controller) from where you can return it via @ControllerAdvice to the requesting application.

Comment: If there is no null checks at service you expect NPE... 
Thanks for sharing your views. Seems like you think because front facing component is controller so that should be enough.
9 out of 10 cases that's right.
Living in ditributed teams service written by developer 1 and unit tested and controller written by developer 2 and unit tested might have common checks in both components.
I was trying to find how people address such scenario.
Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I would do both.

In your example you seem to have both methods refer to `Employee`, which might be possible in very simple scenarios, but in practical scenarios this is not.

It is more likely that you are going to have an `EmployeeDTO` which has JSON properties mapped to Java object fields. You might even have more specific DTOs to specific employee operations (for example change password), depending on what forms your UI is exposing. This will be received by your controller, and JSR303 can help do *syntactic* validations, like checking the string is not empty, that a name does not contain numbers etc.
The DTO should not bleed in to the service, but its data should be translated to whatever the service is expecting, which should be decoupled from the inputs of the controller.

Your Service will then receive an `Employee`. This could be a JPA Entity if it makes sense, or some other intermediate domain object related to the operation being performed. The creation of the `Employee` should ideally already enforce some simple checks (for example non null checks), to ensure that the object is consistent after construction. The service itself should then validate what it is receiving, independently of what the controller validates. The service could be used by other controllers, or invoked by other services in the future, so you should always program defensively. The service could also do more logical checks (for example does another employee with the same ID but different details exist? etc.) This will do business logic validation that will enforce further robustness.

If you see a lot of common code between the DTO and the Entity, or intermediate objects, there are also mapper utility libraries which can help you avoid repetition, like MapStruct.

Comment: I agree, mostly DTOs... I intentionally put this example to make it understandable... So you saying we should validate Not Nulls on DTO and also should validate on Employee object in this case... as the same service might be used in different other objects... This is where I was referring to duplicate logic.

Comment: Yes, in general that is the approach you see most commonly. The service has to be robust to be used by other components safely. (Also think about having other controllers for mobile apps for example). On the other hand the controller itself might be doing some preliminary logic on the DTO, so again makes sense to have declarative JSR303 validations. Furthermore, if you use something like Swagger, the code generation will automatically include JSR303 validations, so it will be 'contract first' DTO generation in sync with your REST API.